# Netbeans 7.4 php highlight error

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-7.4

I use(try to use) Netbeans 7.4 in Linux Mint 14(xfce) to write PHP code. I can write, save... but I don't have highlighting for PHP code. Even don't have an option to open php project. When I wanna write PHP code I use "Empty File" than save as .php file.

Comment: Did you download the php version of NetBeans (or the "full" one)?

Comment: apparently not. :/
I downloaded it form this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html It seems that is Java version. Is there any way to upgrade to PHP version?

Comment: It might be, but I don't use Netbeans so I do not know how. It would be easier to head over the NetBeans website and DL the right version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install PHP plugin in Netbeans, try the below steps

> 1. Go to Tools->Plugins
> 2. Select 'Available Plugins' Tab in Plugins window.
> 3. Check "PHP" from the available plugins. and then click Install.

Now your IDE will support PHP.